# Validate file signature in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, digital-signature, node-crypto

I have a pdf file signed in [Adobe Reader](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/digital-ids.html) with some Key Algorithm, say 1024-bit RSA.
How can I validate the signature in Node.js having both signed file and Public Key?

I know there is a native module [crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_verify). But I cannot understand how to use it, here is an example from docs:

```
const verify = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verify.write('some data to sign'); // should I write pdf file byte stream here?
verify.end();

const publicKey = getPublicKeySomehow();
const signature = getSignatureToVerify(); // this is not clear, what is the signature in current context?
console.log(verify.verify(publicKey, signature));
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

**UPD**
    from what I found here is the proper way to use it:

```
const res = verify.verify(fs.readFileSync('cert.cer'), fs.readFileSync('signed_doc.pdf'))
```

but it throws the next error

```
Error: PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed
    at Error (native)
    at Verify.verify (crypto.js:311:23)
```

**Question:** can I use `Verify.verify` with `p7c`, `cer` certificates?

Comment: You don't have a signature file, do you? Instead you have a signed document that already contains the signature. You can't verify the integrity of the pdf document based on file level verification. You need a pdf specific verifier.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks, you're correct. As I cannot verify the integrity of pdf without using some specific tools probably I need another approach. In case a user has file signature, how it could be delivered to the server?